# Create new type of input type

Tags: javascript, html, input

I was wondering if it was possible to create a new kind of input, as opposed to the normal number, text, etc. For example, I am making a forest fire model for my internship, and one thing I am trying to add is wind. I was wondering if I could do something like `<input type='wind'/>` and define what that would look like and how it would behave. I could do it some other ways, but I also just wanted to know if it would be possible to do something like this.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of available `input` types is here: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/input

The `type` attribute is enumerated (i.e. you can only use those values) with default of text.

However there is nothing stopping you from adding `class="wind"` or the like to the input and using JavaScript to alter the behavior of all such inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, nothing really prevents you from writing `<input type='wind'/>` in HTML and styling and scripting it, e.g. (using jQuery) `$('input[type=wind]').click(handler)`. It won’t be valid HTML, but this just means it does no conform to specifications; browsers don’t care about that. They will treat the element as a normal text input box, because they do not recognize the attribute value and will therefore use the default `type='text'`. This means that the DOM node has `text` as the value of the `type` property, but its `attributes` array (well, array-like object) still has `wind` as the value for `type`

So it would be like using `<input class='wind'>`, as suggested by @ExplosionPills, just using a different attribute name, and with extra complications. Either way, the fallback (in situations where scripting is disabled) is an ordinary text input box.

If the fallback is not relevant (the page would not work at all without JavaScript), it would be simplest to use a `span` or `div` element with `class` and implement it the way you like. Then you would not have to deal with the default rendering and behavior of normal text input box; it can be a bit tricky to wipe them out in favor of your own rendering and functionality.